# CodeIgniter: How to load my own class of static functions into a controller?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a class of static functions (common utility functions) that I wish to load into codeigniter. Currently I am loading it normally using an `include_once(...)` and it works as expected.

However, I want to load it using codeigniter's methodology. I understand that I should save my class file into the third_party directory; and that I should create a library class (saving it in the library directory) which requires my class.

Below are the three components, but it does not work.

**1**

```
// my class, saved at: APPPATH.'third_party/My_Class.php'
class My_Class  
  {
    public static function my_static_utility_method (  )
      {
        return "booger" ;
      }

    // ...
  }
```

**2 -** *I understand that I am supposed to create a wrapper that obeys the CI rules of 'library' instantiation:*

```
// saved at: APPPATH.'libraries/Library_Wrapper.php'
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Library_Wrapper 
  {
    public function __construct()
      {
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/My_Class.php';
      }
  }
```

**3 -** *Now I want to access the static methods of My_Class from my controller:*

```
// saved at: APPPATH.'controllers/my_controller.php'
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller
  { 

    public function __constructor( )
      {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library( 'Library_Wrapper' ) ; 
      }

    public function some_function()
      {
        echo $this->My_Class->my_static_utility_method( ) ;
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Create a new controller file: `application/core/MY_Controller.php`. In that file you may add your static functions.

   ```
   <?php

   class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

       protected function static_fn1() {
           //code
       }
   }
   ```
2. The controllers which need to access the static functions may extend this class like:
   File: `application/controllers/Welcome.php` :

   ```
   <?php

   class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

       public function fnname() {
           //code
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: If using CI3 and up first letter of class and file name of controllers should be applied As says here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: I don't believe the uppercase letter actually has any real functional effect ??

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got the 3rd step in place but not quite. Loading the library will take the same name that you loaded it with:

```
//Load library
$this->load->library( 'Some_name' );
//Use Library
$this->some_name->someFunction();
```

So in your case, you'd need to switch method which accesses the library from:

```
//Will throw an PHP undefined My_Class error
echo $this->My_Class->my_static_utility_method();
```

to `Library_wrapper` instead:

```
//from $this->load->library( 'Library_wrapper' );
echo $this->library_wrapper->my_static_utility_method();
```

But this presents the next problem as My_Class is a property of `library_wrapper` so calling it gets a bit lengthy:

```
echo $this->library_wrapper->My_Class->my_static_utility_method();
```

Which should successfully call the `My_Class` descendent methods if publicly accessible.

This isn't clean as you would perfer. It would better to extend `My_Class` into `Library_wrapper` instead to share the static instances:

```
/**
 * Static helper methods:
**/
class Library_wrapper extends My_Class {

}
```

It *is* possible to bind the 'load' the library to a [different name](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::library) (See "Assigning a Library to a different object name" header).

Comment: unfortunately it is not working ... I still get `Fatal error: Call to a member function my_static_utility_method() on a non-object in C:\Server\htdocs\...\my_controller.php on line 25` ... ... however I will also play around with extending from the library (instead of requiring) ... thanks for your answer and time

Comment: The other commenter @wolfgang1983 is correct that it does matter on the case sensitivity of the Classes and methods you are calling in CodeIgnitier. Especially ones that call from the Controller because in PHP, Class properties are case sensitive ([See example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dcc47517e618afe20526e654127daff3b9f624aa)) so just remember to think of `ucfirst` when it comes to the `$this->load` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below:

in this hierarchy $this->library_wrapper->My_Class->my_static_utility_method();

use the php function listed at [Php Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php) to find out the methods/variables at each point in the hierarchy. This will pin point to the exact location where the things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I do NOT think you need to construct a class. The easiest way would be a helper (*"Helpers, as the name suggests, help you with tasks. Each helper file is simply a collection of functions in a particular category"* - just read the article from the [official tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html)).

Your helper file with a name like `myfunctions_helper.php` will be located into `/application/helpers` folder and could have a structure like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!function_exists('my_static_fuction')) {
   function my_static_fuction (  )
   {
      return "booger" ;
   }
}

// etc...
```

Then you can autoload the helper declaring it to the `/application/config/autoload.php`.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','myfunctions');
```

If you need to construct a class then a library like @MackieeE wrote will do the job ([check the tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/libraries.html) for more info).